# KnockoutJS e ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, knockoutjs

Então, estou começando a dar uma estudada no KnockoutJS e está tudo um pouco sombrio ainda, no exemplo que estou seguindo, estou tendo um erro que diz que `O objeto não oferece suporte à propriedade ou método 'join'`.

meu JS

```
function setupHubClient() {
    socialHubClient = $.connection.socialHub;

    // Inicia a conexão
    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        socialHubClient.join(userInfo.Nome);
    }).done(function () {
        window.isSignalREnabled = true;
        if (window.muralViewModel) {
            window.muralViewModel.isSignalREnabled(true);
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        alert('Conexão SignalR falhou!');
    });    
}
```

Meu Hub

```
public class SocialHub : Hub
    {           

        public void Join(string nome)
        {
            ChatModel.Clients.Add(new Client() { Name = nome, LastResponse = DateTime.Now });
            Clients.Caller.Nome = nome;            
        }
    }
```

meu `signalr/hubs`

```
/*!
 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.2.0
 * http://signalr.net/
 *
 * Copyright Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache 2.0
 * https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 *
 */

/// <reference path="..\..\SignalR.Client.JS\Scripts\jquery-1.6.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR.js" />
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />
    "use strict";

    if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }

    var signalR = $.signalR;

    function makeProxyCallback(hub, callback) {
        return function () {
            // Call the client hub method
            callback.apply(hub, $.makeArray(arguments));
        };
    }

    function registerHubProxies(instance, shouldSubscribe) {
        var key, hub, memberKey, memberValue, subscriptionMethod;

        for (key in instance) {
            if (instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                hub = instance[key];

                if (!(hub.hubName)) {
                    // Not a client hub
                    continue;
                }

                if (shouldSubscribe) {
                    // We want to subscribe to the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.on;
                } else {
                    // We want to unsubscribe from the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.off;
                }

                // Loop through all members on the hub and find client hub functions to subscribe/unsubscribe
                for (memberKey in hub.client) {
                    if (hub.client.hasOwnProperty(memberKey)) {
                        memberValue = hub.client[memberKey];

                        if (!$.isFunction(memberValue)) {
                            // Not a client hub function
                            continue;
                        }

                        subscriptionMethod.call(hub, memberKey, makeProxyCallback(hub, memberValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies = function () {
        var proxies = {};
        this.starting(function () {
            // Register the hub proxies as subscribed
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, true);

            this._registerSubscribedHubs();
        }).disconnected(function () {
            // Unsubscribe all hub proxies when we "disconnect".  This is to ensure that we do not re-add functional call backs.
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, false);
        });

        proxies['socialHub'] = this.createHubProxy('socialHub'); 
        proxies['socialHub'].client = { };
        proxies['socialHub'].server = {
            enviarComentarioParaServidor: function (comentarioPaiId, texto) {
                return proxies['socialHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['socialHub'], $.merge(["EnviarComentarioParaServidor"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            enviarCurtirParaServidor: function (comentarioId) {
                return proxies['socialHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['socialHub'], $.merge(["EnviarCurtirParaServidor"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            enviarDescurtirParaServidor: function (messageId) {
                return proxies['socialHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['socialHub'], $.merge(["EnviarDescurtirParaServidor"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            join: function (nome) {
                return proxies['socialHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['socialHub'], $.merge(["Join"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             }
        };

        return proxies;
    };

    signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    $.extend(signalR, signalR.hub.createHubProxies());

}(window.jQuery, window));
```

Meu _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/NetMagazineIcon.png")" type="image/ico">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @*    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>*@

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Minha view

```
@model Chat.Domain.Model.Usuario
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Social Chat";
}

@section Scripts {

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/social.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var userInfo = {
            Id: @ViewData.Model.Id,
            Nome: '@ViewData.Model.Nome',
            SmallPicturePath: 'Content/images/actor' + @ViewData.Model.Id + '_small.gif',
            MediumPicturePath: 'Content/images/actor' + @ViewData.Model.Id + '_medium.gif'
        };
        window.userInfo = userInfo;
    </script>
}

<div class="photoContainer">
    <div class="largePhotoContainer">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Background" + @ViewData.Model.Id + ".jpg")" width="1024" height="256" class="largePhoto" />
    </div>
    <h2 class="nameContainer">@ViewData.Model.Nome</h2>
    <div class="smallPhotoContainer">
        <div class="smallPhotoBorder">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/actor" + @ViewData.Model.Id + "_large.gif")" width="100" height="100" class="smallPhoto" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/facebook-loading.gif")" class="wall-loading" id="loading-wall-messages" />
    <div class="ajax-error" style="display: none;"><img src="Content/images/exclamation.png" width="32" height="32" /><span>Estamos com problemas para acessar os dados. Por favor recarregue a página.</span></div>
    <!-- ko if: $root.isSignalREnabled -->
    <div class="post-comment post-message">
        <div class="message">
            <textarea class="message-textarea" data-bind="value: novoComentario, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: commentKeypress, focus: commentFocus, blur: commentFocusout, mouseenter: commentMouseEnter, mouseleave: commentMouseLeave }"></textarea>
            <span class="comment-watermark" data-bind="style: {display: mostrarMarcaDAgua() ? '' : 'none'}, event: { click: commentClick, mouseenter: commentMouseEnter, mouseleave: commentMouseLeave }">No que você está pensando?</span>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <div class="wall-messages" style="display: none;">
        <!-- ko foreach: comentarios-->
        <div class="message-thread">
            <div class="message-thread-author"></div>
            <div class="thread-conversation" data-bind="attr: {threadConversationMessageId: id}">
                <span><img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Content/images/actor' + usuario().Id + '_medium.gif'}" class="actor-image-medium" /></span>
                <div>
                    <div class="author-name" data-bind="text: usuario().Nome">
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-text" data-bind="text: texto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-info">
                        <span data-bind="text: tempoDecorrido"></span> ·
                        <span data-bind="ifnot: $parent.isSignalREnabled">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("Content/images/loading_small.gif")" />
                        </span>
                        <!-- ko if: $parent.isSignalREnabled -->
                        <span>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="post-info-link like"
                               data-bind="style: { display: curtidoPorEsteUsuario() ? 'none' : ''},
                            click: curtir">Curtir</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="post-info-link unlike"
                               data-bind="style: { display: curtidoPorEsteUsuario() ? '' : 'none'},
                            click: descurtir">Curtir (Desfazer)</a>
                        </span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="balloonEdge"></div>
                <div class="balloonBody">
                    <div class="UIImageBlock clearfix">
                        <a class="likeIconLabel" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                            <label class="likeIconLabel" title="Like this item" onclick="this.form.like.click();">
                            </label>
                        </a>
                        <!-- ko if: curtiram().length > 0 -->
                        <div class="likeInfo"
                             data-bind="text: sumarioDeCurtidas,
                        style: {display: sumarioDeCurtidas().trim().length > 0 ? '' : 'none'}">
                        </div>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reply-container">
                    <!-- ko foreach: comentarios -->
                    <div class="post-comment">
                        <div class="comment-author">
                            <img data-bind="attr: {src: 'Content/images/actor' + usuario().Id + '_small.gif'}" class="actor-image-small" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment" data-bind="attr: {answerId: id}">
                            <div class="author-name" data-bind="text: usuario().Nome">
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-text" data-bind="text: texto">
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <span data-bind="text: tempoDecorrido"></span> ·
                            <span data-bind="ifnot: $root.isSignalREnabled">
                                <img src="@Url.Content("Content/images/loading_small.gif")" />
                            </span>
                            <!-- ko if: $root.isSignalREnabled -->
                            <span>
                                <a href="javascript:like(1);" class="post-info-link"
                                   data-bind="style: { display: curtidoPorEsteUsuario() ? 'none' : ''}, click: curtir">Curtir</a>
                                <a href="javascript:like(1);" class="post-info-link"
                                   data-bind="style: { display: curtidoPorEsteUsuario() ? '' : 'none'}, click: descurtir">Curtir (Desfazer)</a>
                            </span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <div class="likeInfo" data-bind="text: sumarioDeCurtidas,
                            style: {display: sumarioDeCurtidas().trim().length > 0 ? '' : 'none'}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <!-- ko if: $root.isSignalREnabled -->
                <div class="reply-container">
                    <div class="post-comment">
                        <div class="comment-author">
                            <img src="@ViewData.Model.SmallPicturePath" class="actor-image-small" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment">
                            <input class="comment-textarea" data-bind="value: novoComentario, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: commentKeypress, focus: commentFocus, blur: commentFocusout, mouseenter: commentMouseEnter, mouseleave: commentMouseLeave }" />
                            <span class="comment-watermark" data-bind="style: {display: mostrarMarcaDAgua() ? '' : 'none'}, event: { click: commentClick, mouseenter: commentMouseEnter, mouseleave: commentMouseLeave }">Digite um comentário aqui...</span>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <br />
    </div>
</p>
```

Meu BundleConfig

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
```

O que poderia estar faltando para o JS reconhecer o método `Join`?

Comment: Como estão os Bundles do projeto?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez editei e adicionei o código gerado pelo SignalR, acho que é o que me pedistes.

Comment: Na verdade pedi o conteúdo do arquivo `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`.

Comment: ta adicionado, coloquei também minha view index